# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script function not working, javascript file not loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to load a js file in WordPress. Note that the js file is in the root directory of the theme, as is `functions.php`, here is the code in `functions.php`:

```php
function add_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script',get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array (), false, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

This is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you used `wp_head()` in index.php or anywhere else?

Comment: No I haven't. Is this something I am supposed to do?

Comment: Yes. This function is responsible to include your CSS and JS in pages.

Comment: That worked, thankyou so much! I was following this guide on the official wordpress docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/    and it says nothing about having to calli the wp_head() function anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call wp_head()  in index.php

solved by dreygur